# List as parameter in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that works with a parameter that must be a list of 2 keys, like:

```
key1  key2
 1     7
 2     8
 3     9
 1     5
 3     8
```

I cannot use a table valued parameter type.
How can I define a parameter type wich attends to this situation?

Obs.: I already tried to use a varchar(max) as parameter type for each field-key, using commas to separate values and xml parsing in SQL, but this implies in 2 tables with 1 column each, and could not figure out a way to simply put this columns side by side in 1 table.

Comment: `I cannot use a table valued parameter type.` - why?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework to import the procedure and the TVP is not supported.

Comment: What are you running into when you tried it? I googled it and found a link so looks like this would be deable with an SP and TVP. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Stored-Procedure-with-6c194514

Comment: Thanks for the help Igor, I'll look out

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with XML type if you know how to form your XML and retrieve the data

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<root>
                <key>
                    <key1>1</key1>
                    <key2>7</key2>
                </key>
                <key>
                    <key1>2</key1>
                    <key2>8</key2>
                </key>
                <key>
                    <key1>3</key1>
                    <key2>9</key2>
                </key>
                <key>
                    <key1>1</key1>
                    <key2>5</key2>
                </key>
                <key>
                    <key1>3</key1>
                    <key2>8</key2>
                </key>
            </root>'

SELECT  p.value('(./key1)[1]', 'int') AS key1,
        p.value('(./key2)[1]', 'int') AS key2 
FROM    @XML.nodes('/root/key') T(p)


key1        key2
----------- -----------
1           7
2           8
3           9
1           5
3           8
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. I'm not providing the XML in the application side, but using a single parameter I could generate a proper XML and get the result expected. Thank you.